# Surface Pro 3 won't boot Kaspersky Rescue Disk 10 anymore

Tags: boot, uefi, bootable-media, microsoft-surface, kaspersky

In the past, maybe year ago or more, I once booted my Surface Pro 3 from Kaspersky Rescue Disk 10 installed to a USB flash drive. I disabled Secure Boot in the UEFI and chose proper boot order (USB > SSD). This was probably when Surface ran Windows 8.1 Pro. Everything worked.

But now, on Windows 10 Pro with Anniversary Update I cannot boot Kaspersky Rescue Disk anymore. I've tried to boot Windows Installer from the same drive and it worked. But when it's KRD, it won't. I've tried every possible UEFI settings combination. Tried to start Surface with Volume Down button pressed. I've tried to prepare a USB with Universal USB Installer and with Kaspersky's own USB maker tool, but the result is the same, it won't boot.

Anyone aware of what has been changed? How do we suppose now boot from drives with something other than Windows Installer?

Comment: There has not been a change.  Have you tried to create the drive again?

Comment: Multiple times, with Universal USB Installer and with Kaspersky's own USB maker tool.

Comment: I had no problem booting to my copy of Kaspersky Rescue on my SP3.

Comment: That's a good news. When you tried it last time and was it the latest version of KRD? And what were your UEFI settings?

Comment: I just tried it.

Comment: Well, can you be so kind to provide your UEFI settings when you managed to do it?

Comment: This article seem applicable http://support.kaspersky.com/us/9722

Comment: No, no any useful info at all.

Comment: @Ramhound may I ask you to `dd` your thumbdrive with KRD and somehow share the resulting image? I've tried so many tools to create mine and still no success at all, however Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora and Suse Linux installers all work.